# Is it possible to use canvas blend-mode over parent dom element?

Tags: css, canvas, blending

I'd like to blend a small canvas element over a large parent background element.  I've tried the following without success:

JS:`ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "overlay";`

I believe globalCompositeOperation only works on elements drawn on each other in canvas.

CSS:`background-blend-mode: overlay;`

I thought the css background-blend-mode *might* work, but alas no.

I understand the canvas element is in its own little world and that blending it with other html elements is a shot in the dark - just wanted to confirm I'm not missing anything.

Comment: have you tried CSS mix-blend-mode ?

Comment: @vals woah!  That's why I post here just in case - for my mind to be blown.  YES, mix-blend-mode answers the question.  If you want to make it official, I'll accept ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As vals pointed out in the comments - the answer to my question is: yes, using mix-blend-mode: [css mix-blend-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can draw the "Parent background element" on the canvas and then blend? That might be a bit costly, but it is one of the few options you have I guess.

Comment: Yea, that's the only option I could think of as well.  My canvas clears/animates, so I'd have to draw the entire background over and over in addition to the original - I'd rather not :P